# ajax jquery returns the whole page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, return-value

this question has been asked before but the answers seem not to work on me. My Ajax returns the whole page when i perform a autocomplete search

ajax to search from database

```
$(function(){ $(".search_keyword").keyup(function() { 
var search_keyword_value = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search_keyword='+ search_keyword_value;
if(search_keyword_value!='')
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/search.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
            {
                $("#result").html(html).show();
            }
    });
} else{
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML ='';
}
return false;    });
```

html page

```
<form method="get" action="/?page=results" class="navbar-form" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="query" class="search_keyword"/>
        <button type="submit" nam>Search</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

would really appreciate the help Guys

Comment: What about `search.php`?? Show `search.php` code.

Comment: oh My God , I am A fool, thanks   Indrasinh Bihola for making me realize my error, had misspelled my search.php . thanks man

Comment: if ajax path wont found then it will returns whole page

Answer (score 0):

check whether the page you are calling correct path or not...

due to 404 error only, it will returns whole page. may be the ajax url not found

Answer (score 0):

The url used in ajax should be used to return(echo) the required data only, nothing else.
I've usually resolve this problem passing a 'action' POST to to php page wich contains what i would like to request from it and it gets selected with a switch.
The php code usually looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    switch(action){
      case "func_1":
            func_1();
            break;
      case "func_2":
            func_2();
            break;
      case "func_2":
            func_3();
            break;
      case "func_2":
            func_4();
            break;
    }
} else {
    echo "error";
}

function func_1{
    //do something
}
function func_2{
    //do something
}
function func_3{
    //do something
}
function func_4{
    //do something
}
```

Inside the function I write the desired code, like getting autocompletion data, then echo it wia json, or something.

Also, the ajax 'data' tag capable to do html post/get paramteres via prebuilding a string:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/search.php",
        data: 
        {
            search_keyword : search_keyword_value
        }
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#result").html(html).show();
        }
});
```